# Elasticsearch - how to fuzzy match phrase when search keyword has no spaces?

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

I want to match a document whose field `title` has value `brown fox` by searching with keyword `brownfox`.

When trying this `fuzzy` query I get no results:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/haystack/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "fuzzy" : {
            "title": {
                "value": "brownfox",
                "fuzziness": 2,
                "prefix_length": 0,
                "max_expansions": 10000
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I also tried a `match` query with fuzziness and operator `and`:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/haystack/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "title": {
          "query":     "brownfox",
          "fuzziness": "AUTO",
          "operator":  "and"
        }
      }
    }
}'
```

This returns results with similar keywords, but not the document with title `brown fox` which I would consider a better match.

I also read the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416289/elasticsearch-how-to-find-phrases-if-query-has-no-spaces) SO question, but I don't have the option to update the analyzer of the field with synonyms, since I want to match other similar cases too, including both missing spaces and mis-spelled words.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the mapping of that `title` field. It should, at least, have an analyzer that would keep "brown fox" as a single term. If it's using `standard` analyzer or anything that is not keeping `brown fox` as a whole you'll not be able to match that.

Comment: Yeah i'm afraid I may have to index it both with and without spaces. For some reason I was under the impression that it would be matched using the Levenshtein Edit Distance, I guess not..

Comment: It is using that, but the term it's looking at is `brown` and `fox`. You want to look at `brown fox`.

Comment: That makes more sense now thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping of that `title` field should, at least, have an analyzer that would keep `"brown fox"` as a single term. If it's using `standard` analyzer or anything that is not keeping `brown fox` as a whole you'll not be able to match that.